# Python format negative time

Tags: python

I am writing a program that tracks running performance using Python.

It calculates the runner's pace given the calculated `elapsed_time` and the `distance`.

The issue I am facing is in the calculation of the difference between the runner's pace and their predicted pace. This difference can be positive or negative, as you can run faster than predicted or slower than predicted. However, in the example code (below) I get the result `diff =  23:59:54`. The result I want is `diff = -00:00:06`.

Any ideas on what to do? I had a vague idea that `datetime.timedelta` might help. But as far as I can see there is no way to format a `timedelta` as a string...?

```
import time

def time_to_secs(t):
    hour, minute, seconds = t.split(':')
    adjustedtime = (int(hour)*3600) + (int(minute)*60) + int(seconds)
    return adjustedtime

def time_to_string(t):
    ty_res = time.gmtime(t)
    result = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",ty_res)
    return result

predicted_pace = '00:04:10'
distance = 10.0
elapsed_time = '00:42:42'
pace = time_to_string((time_to_secs(elapsed_time)/distance))

diff = time_to_string(time_to_secs(predicted_pace) - time_to_secs(pace))

print(f'Your total time over {distance} km was {elapsed_time} with a pace of {pace} per km')
print(f'Your predicted pace was {predicted_pace} per km')
print(f'Difference between predicted and actual pace was {diff}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this arises from the way Python's `time.strftime()` function handles times. When you provide a negative number of seconds to `time.strftime()`, it doesn't format it as a negative time.  Instead, it calculates a time that many seconds before the epoch, which is not what you want it seems. You need a custom solution to handle this.

To calculate the difference between the predicted pace and the actual pace and handle negative values properly, you can modify the `time_to_string` function to account for negative `timedelta` values.

Here is an example that might be helpful:

```
import time

def time_to_secs(t):
    hour, minute, seconds = t.split(':')
    adjustedtime = (int(hour) * 3600) + (int(minute) * 60) + int(seconds)
    return adjustedtime

def time_to_string(t):
    negative = False
    if t < 0:
        negative = True
        t = -t  # Make the time positive for calculation
    ty_res = time.gmtime(t)
    result = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", ty_res)
    if negative:
        result = "-" + result
    return result

predicted_pace = '00:04:10'
distance = 10.0
elapsed_time = '00:42:42'
pace = time_to_string((time_to_secs(elapsed_time) / distance))

diff = time_to_string(time_to_secs(predicted_pace) - time_to_secs(pace))

print(f'Your total time over {distance} km was {elapsed_time} with a pace of {pace} per km')
print(f'Your predicted pace was {predicted_pace} per km')
print(f'Difference between predicted and actual pace was {diff}')
```

This code does the following:

1. It first calculates the total seconds for both the predicted pace and the actual pace
2. It then computes the difference in seconds.
3. The code then determines if the difference is negative (meaning the runner was faster than predicted).
4. If the time is negative, it then converts the absolute value of the delta into hours, minutes, and seconds.
5. Finally, the code then formats the result as a string, adding a negative sign if necessary.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also like to offer my own solution:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

def time_to_secs(t):
    hour, minute, seconds = t.split(':')
    return int(hour) * 3600 + int(minute) * 60 + int(seconds)

def format_timedelta(td):
    total_seconds = int(td.total_seconds())
    sign = '-' if total_seconds < 0 else ''
    total_seconds = abs(total_seconds)
    hours, remainder = divmod(total_seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return f"{sign}{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}"

predicted_pace = '00:04:10'
distance = 10.0
elapsed_time = '00:42:42'
pace = timedelta(seconds=time_to_secs(elapsed_time) / distance)

diff = format_timedelta(timedelta(seconds=time_to_secs(predicted_pace)) - pace)

print(f'Your total time over {distance} km was {elapsed_time} with a pace of {format_timedelta(pace)} per km')
print(f'Your predicted pace was {predicted_pace} per km')
print(f'Difference between predicted and actual pace was {diff}')
```

Output:

```
Your total time over 10.0 km was 00:42:42 with a pace of 00:04:16 per km
Your predicted pace was 00:04:10 per km
Difference between predicted and actual pace was -00:00:06
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the code provided by @Anthony Zappin works but I thought I'd share my own solution as well. You should probably be using the datetime library. For example, you could use the function strptime() to format your dates (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Using the datetime class can help standardize your date format while providing an easy way to perform basic arithmetic (timedelta). You can look up the docs and play around. Anyway, here is my code:

```
import time


def time_to_secs(t):
    hour, minute, seconds = t.split(':')
    adjustedtime = (int(hour) * 3600) + (int(minute) * 60) + int(seconds)
    return adjustedtime


def time_to_string(t):
    ty_res = time.gmtime(t)
    result = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", ty_res)
    return result


def showDiff(diff):
    if str(diff)[0] == '-':
        sign = '-'
    else:
        sign = ''
    hours = abs(diff) // 3600
    minutes = (abs(diff) % 3600) // 60
    seconds = (abs(diff) % 3600) % 60
    if hours < 10:
        hours = f'0{hours}'
    if minutes < 10:
        minutes = f'0{minutes}'
    if seconds < 10:
        seconds = f'0{seconds}'
    return f'{sign}{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}'


predicted_pace = '00:04:10'
distance = 10.0
elapsed_time = '00:42:42'
pace = time_to_string((time_to_secs(elapsed_time) / distance))
print(time_to_secs(predicted_pace) - time_to_secs(pace))
diff = showDiff(time_to_secs(predicted_pace) - time_to_secs(pace))

print(f'Your total time over {distance} km was {elapsed_time} with a pace of {pace} per km')
print(f'Your predicted pace was {predicted_pace} per km')
print(f'Difference between predicted and actual pace was {diff}')
```

This isn't necessarily an elegant solution, but it gets the job done. Hope this also helps.

Comment: Hi Max, can you please elaborate on your comment that "You should probably be using the datetime library, as they definitely have an elegant solution to this problem"...

Comment: All of your hours, minutes, seconds have an extra leading zero.  That's not right.

Comment: @ Mark Ransom What exactly do you mean? When I run the code it shows up in the format hh:mm:ss. Isn't that correct formating?

Comment: Try an example where the hours, minutes, or seconds are greater than 9.

Comment: P.S. the way to fix it is to change your f-strings: `f'{hours:02}'`.